# Upgrade SSD for old Macbook Air 6,2

Tags: ssd

I have an old Macbook Air around here and the SSD just went to see it's maker. I know it's quite an old machine, but as a first computer for our daughter (11) I think it should still suffice. I would need to buy a new SSD. The old one is already removed from the unibody, so I have alle the tools and knowledge to do the exchange on the hardware site.

I don't want to use an adapter for a new SSD to fit in the Apple 16+12 socket and I found these models should fit directly. Can anyone proof, that these drives work for a Macbook Air 6,2.

- Transcend Jetdrive 820
- Transcend Jetdrive 850
- OWC Aura N2
- OWC Aura Pro X2

And would I need to take any other steps then just replacing the old drive and then start in recovery mode (I guess) to install an OS? No fancy other stuff like soldering Pin 6078 to 8075 (just some random numbers) or anything like this necessary? Does anyone have experience with one of these SSDs or is there even a cheaper option?

Comment: There are different MacBook Air 6,2 (see https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/index-macbook-air.html), which one is it? Also, did you look at ifixit.com and similar sites (including youtube)?

Comment: There are 4 MacBook Air 6,2, but I don't see any difference in SSD (exchange) here. iFixit only shows a tutorial of how to physically install the SSD. I have removed and reinstalled the old SSD multiple times, so that won't be the problem here. Just read some comments that firmware upgrade might be necessary, which would not be that easy, since my old SSD and so my Mac is completely dysfunctional right now.

Comment: gernophil: Do you know which version of OS X/macOS was the latest version to be installed on the Mac? This would help determine if a firmware upgrade is needed before installing new a SSD.

Comment: I am not absolutely sure. But I think it was Catalina or Big Sur. (Wasn't mine, personally.) However, I bought an identical original SDD (128GB) for 19 EUR with Big Sur on it. Let's hope this works ootb.

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturers should provide you with information about compatibility.
https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-956

The Transcend 820 is the AHCI model, and the 850 the NVMe model.

This webpage contains a detailed guide to the SSDs that Apple uses in various models.

https://beetstech.com/blog/apple-proprietary-ssd-ultimate-guide-to-specs-and-upgrades

From what I can tell, it looks like the Airs only support AHCI, not NVMe, but you may need to confirm this.

You may be able to get an Apple OEM part on eBay. Even a secondhand one should provide you with some years of life.

Bear in mind that a 10-year-old Mac will already have some limitations in terms of compatibility with the latest software, and interacting with iPhones etc that are newer.